# Using a column from :new into a trigger if, multiple errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use a column from :new (the incoming new row) to compare with a date in another table and then Raise an error if the conditions are met.

I have tried two solutions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_example
BEFORE INSERT ON STATION
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    d1 DATE;
    d2 DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT JOUR INTO d1 FROM ELECTION;
    SELECT DATEOUVERTURE INTO d2 FROM NEW;
    IF d1 = d2 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'damn');
    end if;
end;
```

This is the one where I select DATEOUVERTURE from NEW and I get this error.

```
[2021-12-09 01:33:45] 6:39:PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
[2021-12-09 01:33:45] 6:5:PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

But the table exists and I have the appropriate rights to read/write

Second solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_example
BEFORE INSERT ON STATION
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    d1 DATE;
    d2 DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT JOUR INTO d1 FROM ELECTION;
    SELECT DATEOUVERTURE INTO d2 FROM :NEW;
    IF d1 = d2 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'damn');
    end if;
end;
```

This is the one where I select from :NEW instead of NEW. But I get this error.

```
[2021-12-09 01:36:56] 6:39:PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'
[2021-12-09 01:36:56] 6:43:PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name
[2021-12-09 01:36:56] 6:5:PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Any ideas where it went wrong? I've been looking for hours and can't find a single thing.

Comment: What do you get whenever query `SELECT * FROM user_tables WHERE table_name ='NEW'` , doesn't it return a row ?

Comment: It doesn't return any row. In this case, I am not trying to get information from a table called NEW. I am trying to get a specific column on the incoming insert.

Comment: Here it is the reason for returning of `ORA-00942`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `:NEW` like this. Following example should work if you replace

`date_column_on_station_table` to the column you want to compare with inside `STATION` table

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_example
BEFORE INSERT ON STATION
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    d1 DATE;
    d2 DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT JOUR INTO d1 FROM ELECTION;
    IF d1 = :NEW.date_column_on_station_table THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'damn');
    end if;
end;
```

---

**Edit:**
If `DATEOUVERTURE`  is the columns name to compare , then it should be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_example
BEFORE INSERT ON STATION
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    d1 DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT JOUR INTO d1 FROM ELECTION;
    IF d1 = :NEW.DATEOUVERTURE THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'damn');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: When I try this solution I get the error:

Unable to resolve column 'DATEOUVERTURE'

To be noted that the column DATEOUVERTURE is in a Table called STATION and that I am trying to get the incoming DATEOUVERTURE(I'm trying to verify before inserting if the new DATEOUVERTURE is the same as d1)

Comment: hm it should work , can you please check if there is a typo at  DATEOUVERTURE - maybe a missing letter etc ?

Comment: DATEOUVERTURE is correctly spelled.

Comment: i tested it on my oracle db and it works ... i will delete the answer after some time since it doesnt work for you

Comment: To me, your 2nd code looks OK. Though, `d2` can be removed and it is unknown whether `select` will raise an exception (as it stands, that table contains only a single row - beware of TOO_MANY_ROWS or even NO_DATA_FOUND). But that's not the point here - I really believe that this code *should* work, regarding info the OP posted. @Angry_sLmon, please, edit the original code you posted and show tables' descriptions.